# How can I enable/disable a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, controls

Although I have found several answers to this question I somehow don't get it. So please excuse me asking.

I have a WPF application following the MVVM pattern. It contains a button which is bound to a command in the view model:

`<button Content="Login" Command="{Binding ProjectLoginCommand}"/>`

The commands are using `RelayCommand`. Now I would like to do the following:

- The user clicks the button and the corresponding command is executed. This works.
- Within this command another button shall be deactivated, i.e. it shall not be clickable.

I found that this should be possible using `CanExecute` but being honest: I simply don't get it. Hoe can I set the button to enabled/disabled?

This is the `RelayCommand.cs`:

```
namespace MyApp.Helpers {
    class RelayCommand : ICommand {

    readonly Action<object> execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
      if (execute == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

      this.execute = execute;
      this.canExecute = canExecute;           
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      return canExecute == null ? true : canExecute(parameter);
    }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
      add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
      remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {
      execute(parameter);
  }
 }
}
```

This is how I call the command:

```
RelayCommand getProjectListCommand;

public ICommand GetProjectListCommand {
    get {
        if (getProjectListCommand == null) {
            getProjectListCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ProjectLogin());
        }
        return getProjectListCommand;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Execute` and `CanExecute` of both commands?

Comment: Added the command usage. But actually, I don't have code the `Execute` or `CanExecute` except the code in the `RelayCommand` class.

Comment: Thanks Robert. The Button's Enabled/Disabled is automatically tied to the `Command.CanExecute` so you'll need to have Button1 set something that makes `CanButton2Execute` equal to false when it runs, then Button2 will be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the RelayCommand you can specify two methods. The first method is the main method you want to run when the command is invoked. The second method you use to add in checks such as validation, and this should return a bool. if it returns false, then the main method will not run.

How it affects the button you have the command bound to, is it will run the boolean method continually, and while it return false, then the button the command is bound to will be disabled.

So in your command property:

```
public ICommand GetProjectListCommand {
get {
    if (getProjectListCommand == null) {
        getProjectListCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ProjectLogin(), CanProjectLogin());
    }
    return getProjectListCommand;
}
```

Add in new method:

```
public bool CanProjectLogin()
{
    //here check some properties to make sure everything is set that you'd want to use in your ProjectLogin() method
}
```

you can see how the CanExecute works if you put a break point in the bool method.

Comment: This explanation makes it understandable for me :-) However, the param => statement was missing for the second parameter.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a RelayCommand object you have to pass a can Predicate, which could be (among other things) a method with following signature:

bool MethodName(object parameter).

If you don't need the parameter, use e.g. bool MethodName(), but pass it to RelayCommand constructor like that: (o) => MethodName().

In this method you should do your logic and return a value indicating whether the command can be executed. The rest should be handled by WPF Command infrastructure.

Comment: Forgot to specify: pass the predicate as the second argument in constructor:

new RelayCommand(param => this.ProjectLogin(), param => this.MethodName())

Comment: Thanks, this comment in combintation with emybobs answer just makes it right :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble working with the canExecute callback, you may find it easier to work with a simpler version of RelayCommand:

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand 
{
    readonly Action execute;
    private bool canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute) 
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = true;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute;
    }

    public void SetCanExecute(bool canExecute)
    {
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute();
    }
}
```

With this approach, you save references to the RelayCommand objects you make, allowing you to disable the commands like this:

```
getProjectListCommand.SetCanExecute(false);
```