# Wpf Usercontrol, Check if RoutedEvent is bound

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, routed-events, routedevent

I have the following UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DueVCheck.Pl.Gui.CustomControl.ListInfoBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DueVCheck.Pl.Gui.CustomControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ListInfoBar}" >      
    <Button Name="NewRowBtn" Margin="5" Click="NewRowBtn_OnClick" Content="New"/>
</UserControl>
```

The Code-Behind file:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DueVCheck.Pl.Gui.CustomControl
{
    public partial class ListInfoBar
    {       
        public ListInfoBar()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly RoutedEvent NewClickEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("NewClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ListInfoBar));

        public event RoutedEventHandler NewClick
        {
            add { AddHandler(NewClickEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(NewClickEvent, value); }
        }

        private void NewRowBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(NewClickEvent)); }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of the Usercontrol:

```
<customControl:ListInfoBar Margin="10,0,10,0" NewClick="NewRowOnClick"/>
```

What i need is that the Usercontrol disables the `NewRowBtn` whenever the NewClick is not bound via XAML. The Problem is that Add or Remove get never called when binding the Event over XAML.
How to fix this?

Comment: If you want to enable/disable a Button based on some logic you should bind its Command property to an ICommand source property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498287/how-can-i-enable-disable-a-button. Hooking up en event handler has nothing to do with bindings.